# Defining matrix function in terms of resolvent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $d\times d$ diagonalizable matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d$. Let
$$r(\lambda)=\lim_{s\to \lambda} (s-\lambda) (s I - A)^{-1}$$

What's the easiest way to see that the following holds?

$$A=\sum_i^d \lambda_i r(\lambda_i)$$

Sanity check in Mathematica:

```
A = {{1, 4, 16}, {18, 20, 4}, {-12, -14, -7}};
ii = IdentityMatrix[3];
r[eig_] := Limit[(s - eig) Inverse[s ii - A], s -> eig];
Total[# r[#] & /@ Eigenvalues[A]] == A
```

Comment: Just checking: Are you assuming that $A$ is $d\times d$ (i.e., has distinct eigenvalues)?

Comment: Yes, it's $d\times d$, edited q. But not sure if "distinct eigenvalues" is a requirement for the formula to work

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is a $d\times d$ diagonalizable matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d$, there is an invertible matrix $U$ such that $A=UDU^{-1}$ and $D={\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d)$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
(sI-A)^{-1}&=[U(sI-D)U^{-1}]^{-1} \\
&=U(sI-D)^{-1}U^{-1} \\
&=U\,{\rm diag}(s-\lambda_1,\ldots,s-\lambda_d)^{-1}U^{-1} \\
&=U\,{\rm diag}\left(\frac{1}{s-\lambda_1},\ldots,
\frac{1}{s-\lambda_d}\right)U^{-1},
\tag{1}
\end{align}
and it follows that
$$
r(\lambda):=\lim_{s\to \lambda} (s-\lambda) (s I - A)^{-1}
=U\,{\rm diag}(\delta(\lambda,\lambda_1),\ldots,\delta(\lambda,\lambda_d))\,U^{-1},
\tag{2}
$$
where
$$
\delta(\lambda,\lambda_j)=
\begin{cases}
   1,\,\text{if $\lambda=\lambda_j$,} \\
   0,\,\text{if $\lambda\neq\lambda_j$.} \tag{3}
\end{cases}
$$
If the eigenvalues are all distinct, $(2)$ implies
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i\,r(\lambda_i)=U\,{\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d)\,
U^{-1}=A. \tag{4}
$$
Equation $(4)$ is not valid if some eigenvalue has multiplicity greater than $1$, but there is an alternative expression that is valid in this case:
$$
\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\lambda\,r(\lambda)=A, \tag{5}
$$
where $\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d\}$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$.